# OnServerClick in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that uses an image (Image is log out) as input type. When the image is clicked you should be logged out, but when the page is getting loaded I am getting exception

> error CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage' does not contain a definition for 'SeverClick' and no extension method
>   'SeverClick' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What could be the issue?

ascx code:

```
<input type="image" id="Logout" runat="server" style="width:47; height:14; border:0; background-color:transparent;" src="../../IMAGES/logoff_hi.gif" alt="Logout" onserverclick="Logout_Click" />
```

code behind: ascx.cs

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage Logout;
```

In page load:

```
Logout.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Logout_Click);
```

Method:

```
protected void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='../../../logout.asp';</script>");
    Session.Clear();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What is *SeverClick*? (as opposed to say, *ServerClick*)

Comment: @mickey please see ascx code

Comment: His point is you have spelled it SeverClick (missing the first r) not ServerClick

Comment: I think that the only problem is that you are missing one r `Logout.ServerClick`

Comment: Typo resolved. Now I am getting the following exception error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler'

Comment: Well, I got the solution. I have modified the code. Changed OnServerClick to OnClick in ascx, commented Logout.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Logout_Click); in ascx.cs and given System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e instead of EventArgs e in function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I have modified the code as following. Changed OnServerClick to OnClick in ascx, commented Logout.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Logout_Click); in ascx.cs and given System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e instead of EventArgs e in function parameter.